# Speedy updating Cassandra from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, cassandra, database-migration

I wish to update my Cassandra db from MySQL db.

Currently, this process takes around 8 hours. The process I follow is:

```
Make all possible queries in MySQL, update the data received into Cassandra
```

p.s: What can be better and a faster approach to do this? (I don't want to use Hive)

Comment: So, that's a one time operation. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Nah! We need to do the update daily.. . :(

Comment: You insert data in mySQL and then pump it to Cassandra? How are you using Cassandra afterwards?

Comment: mysql is used at backend, cassandra at api server

Comment: could you write the data to both systems on intake (when the data enters your system) instead of batch updates?  You may avoid doing the batch sync that way.

Comment: that wont be possible :(

Comment: There is a suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9665206/993133) about creating an **sstable** and using **sstableloader**. Might that be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can do a search about using [Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/). Datastax has a support to use it. http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/sqoop/sqoop_help

> Apache Sqoop is a tool designed for efficiently transferring bulk data
>   between Apache Hadoop and structured datastores such as relational
>   databases.